# Error while connecting to a mysql server using R script

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to use R-studio and R script to connect to mysql database which is on an Ubuntu system. The error is:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (0)

I tried using telnet to connect, but I get an error saying:

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

I tried using `putty`, and I am able to connect to the ubuntu system with proper credentials. But I am unable to connect thru R. Windows firewall has been disabled. Password and IP address are fine. I tried using localhost but no help.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using R studio ??

Comment: yes.. @Harisudhan.A

Comment: can you please brief me, what you have done so far, meant that your queries

Comment: @Harisudhan.A i tried to connect to mysql using R script from RStudio. using the following code     (i have the RMysql library)                                                 
   drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv,  dbname = "dbname",
                 port = 3306,
                 host = "x.x.x.x",
                 user="username",
                 password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))

Comment: can you try another method, without calling the dbDriver method,

Comment: @Harisudhan.A what method is it?

Comment: initiate RMySQL library followed by
 mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password', dbname='database_name', host='host')

Comment: @Harisudhan.A no luck, same error

Comment: I know it's basic settings, but did you check if mysql listen on port 3306 and this port is accessible.

Comment: @A.Suliman yes i checked. i have opened port 3306 and i have given all rights so that i can access it. when i do "telnet" , i am unable to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. there were some internal issues, otherwise, everything as fine. the port was open and the password was right..